# create an object with properties to reflect its input field name and assign its value

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, serialization, input

I have a React app that has [controlled input fields](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components), at the moment I'm having problem trying to build an object from the input field name/path and assigning value to it.

Say a form generates an input of:

```
<input
    type="text"
    name="field_5b55440b965b1[value][1][field_5b554428965b2]"
    placeholder=""
    value="foo"
>
```

its name is: `field_5b55440b965b1[value][1][field_5b554428965b2]` with value of `foo`

how can I build an object from such name => value pair like:

```
{
    field_5b55440b965b1: {
        value: [
            field_5b554428965b2: '',
            field_5b554428965b2: 'foo',
        ]
    }
}
```

At the moment, the solution I have is use [`qs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) package.
I build the object something like this:

```
$object = qs.parse(`${name}=${value}`, { arrayLimit: 0 });
```

It is successful on most cases: https://runkit.com/embed/pm2ha1inhj3o

But it fails if the value has `&` (ampersand) in it: https://runkit.com/embed/qeczd27l5xr7

Now, I'm looking for other possible solution or packages. There are this packages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/set-value - but it only allows `.`(dot) path

https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-serialize - but you need the DOM of the form, not the single input field.

Hope somebody can help.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

why not using some regex to extract from the name all levels and then use a loop to go over the list to generate the object?

```
var levels = name.match(/regex/);
let $object = {}
let intermediate = $object
for(var i = 0; i < levels.length; i++) {
    intermediate[levels[i]] = (i === levels.length - 1) ? $value : {}
    intermediate = intermediate[levels[i]]
}
```

Sorry for the regex, i am not good enough so i prefer to let you check for it.